# not getting $rootScope.updatedata from controller to html view

Tags: angularjs, json, spring

I am trying to get `$rootScope.updatedata` from the controller to the view using `$rootScope` of angularjs. When I pass the data gotten from the server response to the view, the data is null. From the controller, the data has a value. Here is the snippets

```
app.controller("updateCtrl",["$scope","$rootScope","$location","$cookies","$http",
                            function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$cookies,$http){
    getUserDetails: function (email) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/updateprofile',
                params: {email: email}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.status == 204) {
                } else if (response.status == 200) {


                    alert("email24 "+response.data); //this returns an object
                    $rootScope.updatedata = response.data; //passing to the view                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        }
    }
```

here is how I am getting it in the view

```
<input formcontrolname="firstName" value="{{updatedata.email}}" />
```

spring controller snippets

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/updateprofile"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json") 
    public ResponseData<Client> updateByEmail( @RequestParam("email") String email) {
```

this is my challenge

Comment: do you have a controller in place (I'm asking because of how you access `updatedata.email` in that input) and where are you calling the `getUserDetails` method? Please add some code where this is called.

Comment: yes I have controller in place... I am calling getUserDetails when this is clicked>>> a ng-click="getUserDetails.getUserDetails(user.email)" class="ui" href="#/dashboard">Edit&nbsp;Profile</a>

Comment: Could you please add code where you define this controller?

Comment: Here is it >>>> app.controller("updateCtrl",["$scope","$rootScope","$location","$cookies","$http",
                            function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$cookies,$http){

Comment: Controllers should avoid using `$rootScope`. See [AngularJS FAQ - `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$rootscope` in this situation will not help you. In general, try avoiding using it, it's a bad practice. Try something like this instead:

```
app.controller("updateCtrl",["$scope","$location","$cookies","$http",
                            function($scope,$location,$cookies,$http){
    $scope.updatedata = {
      email: "",
      //rest of your fields
    };
    getUserDetails: function (email) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/updateprofile',
                params: {email: email}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.status == 204) {
                } else if (response.status == 200) {


                    alert("email24 "+response.data); //this returns an object
                    $scope.updatedata.email = response.data.email; 
                    //populate rest of the fields
            }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: this returns undefined >>> alert("email44 "+response.data.email); So solution not working

Comment: What does `console.log(response.data)` return?

Comment: it returns the actual expected data

Comment: address
:
"wrerere"
city
:
"Ohio"
confirmedEmail
:
true
country
:
"6"
dateOfReg
:
null
dob
:
"2018-05-17"
email
:
"meme@yahoo.com"
firstname
:
"sdsdss"
gender
:
"2: MALE"
id
:
37
lastname
:
"sdsds"
middlename
:
"dsdsds"
nationalidentificationnumber
:
"kjkjkjkjk"
nationality
:
"4"
password
:
"password"
phonenumber
:
"09009009876"
state
:
"39"
username
:
"silver"

Comment: but picking a value is a problem

Comment: Can you pick any value from `response.data`?

Comment: this returns undefined >>>> console.log(value.username); but you can see it there as silver

Comment: Is `response.data` a JSON object? Maybe you need to turn it into a JSON object.

Comment: I am sure I am doing that but how do I turn it to a json object

Comment: just wanted to make sure. when you posted the content of `response.data` object, it was weird seeing it without curly braces and commas.